# Populating Rows Based On Ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query for the accounting department. I have a report template that provides me with **H**eaders, **D**etail, **T**otal, and other row types. Where the row type is "D," I have a range of accounts (Start_Account/End_Account). I'm trying to write a query that will bump up against general ledger data. I'd like to be able to populate each row with the appropriate heading description. Admittedly, I am stumped, short of doing it manually.

```
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------------+
| Report_ID | Row_Sequence | Row_Type | Start_Account | End_Account | Level_Num | Reverse_Sign_Flag |    Heading_Description    |
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------------+
|        06 |          001 | H        |               |             |         1 |                   | CONSTRUCTION INCOME       |
|        06 |          002 | D        |          3000 |        3099 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          003 | D        |          3801 |        3801 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          004 | T        |          3000 |        3099 |        11 | Y                 | TOTAL INCOME              |
|        06 |          005 | I        |          3801 |        3801 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          011 | H        |               |             |         1 |                   | DIRECT CONSTRUCTION COSTS |
|        06 |          012 | D        |          4000 |        4001 |        10 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          013 | D        |          4011 |        4031 |        10 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          014 | D        |          4041 |        4041 |        10 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          015 | T        |          4000 |        4099 |        11 |                   | TOTAL DIRECT EXPENSES     |
|        06 |          016 | E        |          4002 |        4002 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          017 | E        |          4032 |        4032 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          018 | E        |          4051 |        4051 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          019 | T        |          3000 |        3099 |        12 | Y                 | GROSS PROFIT FROM JOBS    |
|        06 |          020 | I        |          3801 |        3801 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          021 | I        |          4000 |        4099 |         0 |                   |                           |
|        06 |          022 | H        |               |             |         1 |                   | OVERHEAD APPLIED TO JOBS  |
|        06 |          023 | D        |          3402 |        3402 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          024 | D        |          3404 |        3404 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          025 | D        |          3417 |        3417 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          026 | D        |          5432 |        5432 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          027 | D        |          5471 |        5471 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          028 | D        |          5494 |        5494 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          029 | D        |          5495 |        5495 |        10 | Y                 |                           |
|        06 |          035 | T        |          3402 |        3402 |        12 | Y                 | ADJUST BURDEN TO ACTUAL   |
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------------+
```

As outputs, I would have:

- Start_Account
- End_Account
- Heading_1
- Heading_2
- Heading_3

Using the JPG:

- Level_Num **1** would correspond to **Heading_1**
- Level_Num **11** would correspond to **Heading_2**
- Levl_Num **12** would be **Heading_3**

So, for example, for Start_Account = 3000, End_Account = 3099:

- **Heading_1** would be "Construction Income,"
- **Heading_2** would be "Total Income,"
- **Heading_3** would be "Gross Profit From Jobs."

Now when I join to the general ledger detail, I'd like to be able to look up the proper header titles based on the start and end accounts.

Comment: Please provide the output as you want it to be.

Comment: Insofar as output, I would have Start_Account, End_Account, Heading_1, Heading_2, and Heading_3. Using the JPG, Level_Num 1 would correspond to Heading_1, Level_Num 11 would correspond to Heading_2, and Levl_Num 12 would be Heading_3. So, for example, Start_Account = 3000, End_Account = 3099, Heading 1 would be "Construction Income," Heading_2 would be "Total Income," and Heading_3 would be "Gross Profit From Jobs." Now when I join to the general ledger detail, I'd like to be able to look up the proper header titles based on the start and end accounts.

Comment: How do I know that "CONSTRUCTION INCOME" should be mapped with Start_Account = 3000 and END_Account = 3099?

Comment: Can we assume for the moment that the rows with the various headings are populated? My challenge is how to write a t-SQL statement that can look through the various account ranges and return the heading descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Anyway here is a script that dynamically creates headings. You will propbably have to adjust the logic to fit your requirements, but it should be a good starting point:

```
declare @startAccount int = 3000
declare @endAccount   int = 3099

declare @tmp table(Report_ID varchar(10), 
                   Row_Sequence varchar(10), 
                   Row_Type varchar(1), 
                   Start_Account int, 
                   End_Account int, 
                   Level_Num int, 
                   Reverse_Sign_Flag varchar(1), 
                   Heading_Description varchar(max))

insert into @tmp values      ('06','001','H',null,null,1 ,'','CONSTRUCTION INCOME')     ,('06','002','D',3000,3099,10,'Y','')   ,('06','003','D',3801,3801,10,'Y','')   ,('06','004','T',3000,3099,11,'Y','TOTAL INCOME')   ,('06','005','I',3801,3801,0 ,'','')    ,('06','011','H',null,null,1 ,'','DIRECT CONSTRUCTION COSTS')   ,('06','012','D',4000,4001,10 ,'','')   ,('06','013','D',4011,4031,10 ,'','')   ,('06','014','D',4041,4041,10 ,'','')   ,('06','015','T',4000,4099,11 ,'','TOTAL DIRECT EXPENSES')  ,('06','016','E',4002,4002,0 ,'','')    ,('06','017','E',4032,4032,0 ,'','')    ,('06','018','E',4051,4051,0 ,'','')    ,('06','019','T',3000,3099,12,'Y','GROSS PROFIT FROM JOBS')     ,('06','020','I',3801,3801,0 ,'','')    ,('06','021','I',4000,4099,0 ,'','')    ,('06','022','H',NULL,NULL,1 ,'','OVERHEAD APPLIED TO JOBS')    ,('06','023','D',3402,3402,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','024','D',3404,3404,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','025','D',3417,3417,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','026','D',5432,5432,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','027','D',5471,5471,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','028','D',5494,5494,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','029','D',5495,5495,10 ,'Y','')  ,('06','035','T',3402,3402,12 ,'Y','ADJUST BURDEN TO ACTUAL')

DECLARE @Heading_1 varchar(100)
      , @Heading_2 varchar(100)
      , @Heading_3 varchar(100)
      , @minRowSequence varchar(10)

select @minRowSequence = min(Row_Sequence) 
from @tmp 
where Start_Account=@startAccount and End_Account=@endAccount 

select @Heading_1 = Heading_Description 
from @tmp 
where isnull(Start_Account,'')='' 
    and isnull(End_Account,'')='' 
    and Level_Num=1 
    and Row_Sequence < @minRowSequence

select @Heading_2 = Heading_Description 
from @tmp 
where Start_Account=@startAccount 
    and End_Account=@endAccount 
    and Level_Num=11

select @Heading_3 = Heading_Description 
from @tmp 
where Start_Account=@startAccount 
    and End_Account=@endAccount 
    and Level_Num=12

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
set @sql = @sql + 'select ' + cast(@startAccount as varchar(max)) + ' AS Start_Account, '
set @sql = @sql + cast(@endAccount as varchar(max)) +' AS End_Account, '  
set @sql = @sql + '''' +  @Heading_1 + ''' AS Heading_1,  '
set @sql = @sql + '''' +  @Heading_2 + ''' AS Heading_2,  '
set @sql = @sql + '''' +  @Heading_3 + ''' AS Heading_3 '

exec(@sql)
```

Output:

[image]